# Moving (very old) Zope/Plone Site to Django

Tags: django, plone, zope

I am ask to move data from a (now offline) site driven by Plone to a new Django site.

These are the version informations I have:

**Zope Version** (unreleased version, python 2.1.3 )

**Python Version 2.1.3** (#1, Sep 19 2002, 13:15:46) [GCC egcs-2.91.66 19990314/Linux (egcs-1.1.2 release)]

**CMFPlone** (Installed product CMFPlone (**1.0.1**)) 2003-04-11 01:17

furthermore I have the complete Data.fs and several Plone-folders exported to xml/zexp

What are good strategies to move?

How can I access a six years old ZODB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handiest option would be if you can get your hands on the complete installation, especially the `Products/` folder.  If you have that, you can probably start it up just fine with python 2.1.  Find the `etc/zope.conf` file, switch on FTP access if not yet enabled and copy everything out of there onto your harddisk.  That's the quickest way to get everything out in a format that you can work with.

Alternative if you don't have access to the complete installation: try to set up an old debian somewhere that contains zope-cmfplone 1.0.1. Copy the Data.fs to the correct location (I'd guess in /var/lib/zope or so on such an old debian) and start the server. And do the FTP trick again.

Alternative 2: if the exported zexp xml contains all the content, you can take a quick look whether you can extract whatever you need from that.

Alternative 3: the Data.fs is readable with a standalone ZODB package. The Data.fs contains python objects that are readable from within python. Get yourself an older zope or standalone zodb package and open the Data.fs.  As you don't have the original software, apparently, the python classes used to make the objects aren't available so the objects will be pretty much broken.  With `dir()` and dictionary access you can try to rescue as much as possible.

Alternative 4: was it a public site? What does http://archive.org have in store for you?

Comment: hm, haven't thought about Zope's ftp interface. With a modern ZODB even the object identifier says broken. Its gonna be a long weekend of data trasition :S ....

Comment: I am having exactly same problem, except the site is still online. Looks like scrapping is better option.

Comment: @chhantyal: scraping can work fine. The site is still online? You could log in to the ZMI and make a zexp xml export, that might give you some more options, depending on the kind of contents.